# C++ best fit data structures

Tags: c++, data-structures

we have set of nodes `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`  and edges (dont need to show here) and assume that after a process which is finding all possible paths between two arbitrary nodes, lets say between `(1,4)`. Than, we got some paths as outputs

```
1 2 4
1 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 3 2 4
```

start and begin nodes are same always. In this case that is (1,4).

Than, we would like to store those outputs to in a suitable data structure (maybe a tree) in order to reorder and reproduce new paths from current outputs (between (1,4)) without looking to the graph again. For instance,suppose that now we want to list all possible paths between (2,4) but not from the graph again, just from the list that we obtain from (1,4). which will be as;

```
2 4 (from 1st line)
2 3 4 (from 3rd line)
2 4 (from 4th line )
```

or for between (3,4);

```
3 4 (from 2nd line)
3 4  (from 3rd line)
3 2 4  (from 4th line)
```

the problem is storing the paths between `(1,4)`, in a such a way that should make easy to produce paths between `(2,4)` from point of searching required nodes (which is `(2,4)`) within paths between`(1,4)`

I believe that most suitable data structure would be a tree in this case, unfortunately I dont have soo much programming experience to solve this problem.

which data structure would be the solution ?
is there anyone to show me an instance implementation ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve this question, I think you can use `Union-Find Sets`，about how to use this structure you can see [here!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

you can find one of path in `O(lgn)`

Answer (score 1):

I would define a new graph including only the nodes and archs which are "touched" by at least one of the results of finding the connections between (1, 4). This way you would have only one "routine" that does the path-searching and everything would be homogeneous.

Comment: but with defining a new graph we will consume more time and memory. I didnt mention about it in the question but assume that we have restrictions. because we could have 10.000 nodes at the beginning in the graph. rebuilding another graph could be really difficult.

Comment: @zaratushtra If you don't need the original graph anymore, you could just prune the extra nodes(5, 6) and in turn the edges.

Comment: especially if you have execution-time constraints, and large graphs, you don't want to have to mantain and optimize two different path-searching algorithms. Memory is most likely not an issue, you can, for example, instantiate a graph holding only shared_ptr<const Node>, which would give you a small footprint (since it only needs to memorize the connections).

Comment: Or, if possible, you can isolate a subgraph from within the old graph, meaning you modify the first one by "internally" splitting it. Of course your original data-structure would need to be able to seamlessly manage a graph of graphs

Comment: I believe that after getting the first list of paths, I dont need to deal with any graph anymore. I could store the paths (which is sequence of numbers now, not really a path )..I might search a specific node (this case a number) in the sequence.If I find the number, I can prune the part till the number and save the part from the number to the source.

Comment: you can do the exact same thing with the first graph, just enumerate all the possible paths from every node to every node. The list of paths is a (clearly suboptimal) tree representation, when you elaborate it you are most probably trying to apply some graph algorithm which is going to be slow and, generally, a pain to write and use. Those are just my two cents, of course I don't claim I'm right.